# TempData Peek Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, tempdata

I am using TempData for temp storage of a list item.
I have used below code in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();
builder.Services.AddSession();

//Other middleware

app.UseSession();
```

On a get request i have created a view model and stored the data from viewmodel into Tempdata as given below

```
 TempData["vMClient"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vMClient);
 return View(vMClient);
```

Now whenever i am using Tempdata.Peek method my browser is throwing error code 431

View Page Code.

```
@model VMClient
@{
    var a = @TempData.Peek("vMClient");    
}
```

[Error Link Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsNzW.png)

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `HTTP Error 431` is caused by passing the `vMClient` parameter to the view: it exceeded header size. And you don't need to do that, because this data is already passing by the `TempData`. What you need is to use `DeserializeObject()`.

Try the following. In the action method:

```cs
 TempData["vMClient"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vMClient);
 return View();
```

In the view:

```cs
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@model VMClient
@{
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VMClient>(TempData.Peek("VMClient").ToString());      
}
```

Comment: Getting same error.

Comment: @user23884828: Clean up the `localhost` cookies in the browser before test and take to account that the [TempData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0#state-management) uses HTTP cookies or session storage mechanism. In case your application is trying to pass to much data I would propose to make Ajax call to load the required data.